# Modificar las propiedades de seguridad de documento PDF con iText7

Tags: c#, itextsharp, vs2017

Tengo un codigo escrito con iTextsharp para modificar las propiedades de seguridad de un documento PDF. El problema es que al cambiar a las nueva versión con iText7 la linea de codigo con las constantes PdfWriter.AllowPrinting, PdfWriter.HideMenubar, PdfWriter.HideToolbar no me las reconoce.

```
private static void CodificarArchivoPdf(string FichOrg, string FichDestino)
{
    using (Stream input = new FileStream(FichOrg, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (Stream output = new FileStream(FichDestino, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
        // Modificar propiedades de seguridad del documento: sólo permitir lo que aparezca como Allow...
        PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, null, null, PdfWriter.AllowPrinting | PdfWriter.HideMenubar | PdfWriter.HideToolbar);
    }
    
    // Nos quedamos solo con el ficheroDestino
    File.Delete(FichOrg);
}
```

Comment: Cual es la version de iTextsharp que estas usando.?

Comment: La version ahora es iText7, la anterior era iTextsharp